# Getting error Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: typescript, function, interface

Getting error when setting return type of a function in interface as string |number
For Example-

```
export interface IRecord{
    getData(field:string):string|number
}

export class Record implements IRecord{
    constructor(private _dummyData:any){
    }

   public getData(field:string):string|number{
        return this._dummyData[field]
    }
}

export interface IData{
    name:string;
    age:number
}

export class abc{

   public getRecords(records:IRecord):IData{

    const myname= records.getData("namefield")
    const myage= records.getData("myage")

    return {name:myname,age:myage}
}
```

Getting error here for both properties name and age of interface IData like below-
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

I tried below but its not working.I can't typecast the return type of name and age  ,as I have to use interface IData at many places.

`export interface IRecord{ getData():string|number }`

Comment: There are [quite a few errors](https://tsplay.dev/N9b07m) in that code; could you [edit] it to be a [mre] where the only problem is the one you're asking about?

Comment: @jcalz I have updated the code,if you now open it to check the errors,you will see the error in last line only,which is exactly the error I am asking about.Please let me know incase you still have any doubts

Comment: I also see an error with the class not being properly terminated; you're missing a closing `}`.  Obviously this is easy for me to fix, but part of the idea of a [mre] is to make things as straightforward as possible for others to help.  You're not asking about syntax errors, so your code shouldn't include syntax errors.  Does that make sense?

Comment: The actual problem you're having is because `IRecord` doesn't promise to return `IData`-compatible data, just "a `string` or a `number`".  I could write [this](//tsplay.dev/WyqnbW) and it meets that criteria, always returning a number, which then explodes at runtime.  I'm confused about how to proceed and what you're allowed to change.  `IRecord` is too loosely typed.  You're going to have to either check the return values like [this](//tsplay.dev/W4jzON) or you're going to have to make `IRecord` stronger like [this](//tsplay.dev/NaEe2N). Does either of those approaches work for you?